# Odd Exception in MVC 3 Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm getting an odd error with a MVC 3.0 RC project.

It seems that it is upset about my application not being a **homogenous AppDomain**
It was working fine yesterday, not sure what's changed.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
Message=Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain.
Source=System.Core
StackTrace:
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore[T](CallSite`1 site, Object[] args)
    at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
    at ASP.Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Projects\RealJobs.Branch\RealJobs.MVC\Views\Jobs\Index.cshtml:line 5
    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
    at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
    at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
    at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
    at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
    at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
    at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

The exception is been thrown when the View.Title is modified in the Index.cshtml

```
@{
   View.Title = "Jobs | realjobs.com.au";
}
```

Any ideas?  Google yielded no joy.

### UPDATE

Seems like it really didn't like me changing the trust in the web.config

I'd added the following line to get around another issue:

```
<trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full"/>
```

Once removed it is working again.  Is this by design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I believe that this is expected.

There are some limitations with using dynamic dispatching like this. The new `dynamic` feature in .NET 4 wasn't meant to be used for things like this, but it sure is nice when it works out great in many cases. The main intention of `dynamic` was for better COM interop.

For example, some other scenarios that don't work are using dynamic dispatch in VB in a Medium Trust application.