# "dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous appdomain" error while launching PowerShell

Tags: powershell, automation, code-access-security

I have a powershell script that I am trying to execute from WCF REST service.I am using the `System.Management.Automation` and `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces` assemblies.

The C# code looks like this:

```cs
Command command = new Command(path);
command.Parameters.Add(param);
RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration))
{
    runspace.Open();
    ... other code
}
```

This error happens here once I try to execute the open statement:

> Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain.

I have looked and looked but nothing worked. I have tried adding this line to my web.config:
 
But it didn't do anything for me.

Do you have thoughts?

Comment: What is `legacyCasPolicy` in the config set to? Also does `NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy` exist?

Comment: awesome!! Adding what you said fixed the issue. Now, I have those web.config setup like this: <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/> <trust legacyCasModel="false" level="Full" />
Please make it a solution, so I mark it.

Comment: The German error term is "**Dynamische Vorgänge können nur in einer homogenen AppDomain durchgeführt werden.**", just in case someone is googling this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just googled that error and it seemed to be related to `legacyCasPolicy` being set to true as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761113/dynamic-operations-can-only-be-performed-in-homogenous-appdomain-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541143/legacycasmodel-true-and-dynamic-data-operations). It turns setting it to false resolved your issue as well. Detailed information about this configuration element can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5tk9z76.aspx).

Comment: As far as I see, you should now use `legacyCasModel` instead of `legacyCasPolicy`. The referenced SO threads mention it as well.